# Failure during boot with service failures (slowing down PC)

Tags: boot, log, udev, dbus, init.d

While Ubuntu is starting and showing it's boot screen an error occurs for several times saying:

```
failed to execute 'lib/udev/socket:4/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event' 'socket:0/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event': No such file or directory
```

**I don't know where this comes from but would like to find out and make it stop.**

I just guessed it is a service so I grep for "freedesktop":

```
/etc/init.d% grep freede *    
dbus:            --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus \
dbus:            / org.freedesktop.DBus.ReloadConfig > /dev/null
```

Can someone help me getting rid of it? 
Do you need additional information?

Because from time to time my PC just freezes for some seconds and comes back which might be up to the service trying to start over and over again (after being blocked for some minutes due to it's errors).

Answer (score 0):

Some resources might be missing. Try updating you ubuntu. Run below mentioned command in terminal.

> sudo apt-get update

Comment: Did this but all packages were already up to date. The error still occurs during boot.